# Flutter error: type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter

I developed a app using flutter 1.0. The app works well on most android and ios phones. But I found there one android phone and one iphone can not open that app, just show the error message "type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'double'". Is there someone can tell me what's going on my app.

Error picture when open the flutter app:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to tell without the relevant piece of code, but in my case, this happened when trying to assign a double value from a Map. The solution was simply to call .toDouble on the value:

```dart
// myMap is a Map<String, dynamic>
double myDouble = myMap['mykey'].toDouble();
```

It used to work without the .toDouble(), but the _Smi error started happening one day.

Answer (score 4):

_Smi stands for Small machine integers, according to [Dart Cookbook](https://manualzz.com/doc/o/t3sk7/dart-cookbook---all-it-ebooks-improving-performance-in-numerical-computations)

So basically you're getting an int and parsing it incorrectly.

Comment: The Dart Cookbook link here is now a dead link, do you have a new version?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and settled on this.

Try to replace this:

```
double myDouble = myMap['mykey'].toDouble();
```

To this:

```
double myDouble = double.parse(myMap['mykey'].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using firestore (from google firebase) and you are having fields in a document that are stored as `number` (only number available, so number is used for int, double, float, ...) - make sure that you use `.toDouble()` before assigning the field value of a document to a double field in your model class in dart.

Example:

```
final collectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

final products = await collectionReference.get();

List productsDocuments = products.docs
        .map((doc) => doc.data())
        .toList();

items = Items.fromList(productsDocuments);

List<Item> items;
  factory Items.fromList(docsFirebase) => Items(
      items: List<Item>.from(docsFirebase.map((docFirebase) => Item(
          itemName: docFirebase['item_name'],
          variantId: docFirebase['variant_id'],
          imageUrl: docFirebase['image_url'],
          barcode: docFirebase['barcode'],
          defaultPrice: docFirebase['default_price'].toDouble(),
          lowStock: docFirebase['low_stock'],
          optimalStock: docFirebase['optimal_stock']))));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this helped me to read json from another api.

```
double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'].toDouble();
```